# Need help understanding a basic Python script for parsing a file

Tags: file-io, split

Assume that the input file "input.txt" looks like the following:

```
Sam   92
Zoe   80
Ted   45
Sue   74
```

What is the output of the following code?

```
x = ""
infile = open("input.txt", "r")
for line in infile:
    parts = line.split()
    x += parts[1].strip()
print(x)
```

Comment: What is your question? What problem are you facing with this code?

Comment: Fix your title, explain your problem clearly. This is off-topic as unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Lori, welcome to SO! Please read the community guidelines on how to use the different tools just above the text editor to make your question clearly readable by other users.

In regard to your question, let's break it down:

```
1  x = ""
2  infile = open("input.txt","r")
3  for line in infile.readlines():
4      parts = line.split()
5      x += parts[1].strip()
6  print x
```

Line 2 calls the `open()` method which creates a new object through which you can read a file (notice the "r" flag which means the file can only be read). Then, a for loop is executed for each line in the file (there's an error in line 3, I've added the `readlines()` method call for it to work).

For each line in the file, **split** the line using space as a delimiter (meaning that a list is created where each element is a substring between two spaces). Then, **concatenate** the second element in the list (this will be the number next to each name) to the variable x, **stripping** any unnecessary white spaces before and after the number. Then, when you're done, **print** x. This will print all the numbers, one after another, without any spacing, like so: **92804574**